# How to load .qml files as list element in QT?

Tags: qt, qml

```
Page
{
    id : root
    focus: true

    ListView
    {
        id : listview
        width: 1250
        height: 400
        focus: true
        orientation: ListView.Horizontal
        snapMode: ListView.SnapOneItem
        model: myModel
        delegate: myDelegate
        preferredHighlightBegin : 0
        preferredHighlightEnd : 0
        highlightRangeMode : ListView.NoHighlightRange
        antialiasing: true
        clip: true

        ListModel {
            id: myModel
            ListElement {
                element: "a.qml"
            }
            ListElement {
                element: "b.qml"
            }
            ListElement {
                element: "c.qml"
            }
            ListElement {
                element: "d.qml"
            }
            ListElement {
                element: "e.qml"
            }
        }

        Component {
            id: myDelegate
            Loader { source: element }
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** Here a.qml, b.qml, c.qml, d.qml and e.qml have a combination of images, Buttons, etc but they are not unique.
I'm able to create a horizontal list with this code and it is not scrolling properly. When tried scrolling by pressing and holding the list element its not scrolling, the spaces apart from the list element is scrollable.
Do we have any solution for this use case?

Comment: It may help if you can supply a screenshot of the issue. Also, if you can upload a minimal reproducible sample somewhere, such as GitHub?

Comment: @StephenQuan: My use case is to create a few non unique Items and add these Items as list element to a Page. I should be able to both flick and click the list elements. Non unique means each Item here can have a combination or any one of the following: Image, Button, Row, etc.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>It is not clear what the width and height of each delegate are. I would recommend, as a starting point, setting the width and height of each Loader instance, e.g.</strike>

```
Loader {
    source: element
    width: ListView.view.width
    height: 100
}
```

I still think your problem may be due to sizing. There are several things to look at. The size of your app, the size of your Page, the size of your ListView.

```
//MyApp.qml
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
Window {
    id: app
    width: 300
    height: 300
    MyPage {
        anchors.fill: parent
    }
}

//MyPage.qml
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
Page {
    ListView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: ListModel {
            id: myModel
            ListElement { element: "a.qml" }
            ListElement { element: "b.qml" }
            ListElement { element: "c.qml" }
            ListElement { element: "d.qml" }
            ListElement { element: "e.qml" }
        }
        delegate: Loader { source: element }
    }
}

//a.qml
import QtQuick 2.15
Rectangle { implicitWidth: 200; implicitHeight: 50; color: "red" }

//b.qml
import QtQuick 2.15
Rectangle { implicitWidth: 200; implicitHeight: 50; color: "orange" }

//c.qml
import QtQuick 2.15
Rectangle { implicitWidth: 200; implicitHeight: 50; color: "yellow" }

//d.qml
import QtQuick 2.15
Rectangle { implicitWidth: 200; implicitHeight: 50; color: "green" }

//e.qml
import QtQuick 2.12
Rectangle { implicitWidth: 200; implicitHeight: 50; color: "blue" }
```

[image: rainbow-png]

Comment: Each of the delegate is an "Item" having default height of 400 and width 300, basically a rectangle card. On top of a "Page" am trying to create this list view, but the list is scrollable only in the spaces between the list elements, whenever I try to click and drag the list element(card or rectangle) its not scrollable

Answer (score 0):

if you just need to scroll your list view maybe this code is useful for you :

```
ScrollView{
        anchors.fill: mainrec
        Flickable{
            implicitHeight: lstvw.height
            boundsBehavior:Flickable.StopAtBounds
            anchors.fill: mainrec
            z:0
            ListView{
                ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar {
                        policy: ScrollBar.AlwaysOn
                    }
                id:lstvw
                boundsBehavior: Flickable.StopAtBounds
                width: mainrec.width-10
                height: mainrec.height
                model: reportModel
                delegate: ....
                }
            }
}
```